# How to get 6 cube color picker in swatches?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, swatches

where can i get a swatch panel in Photoshop similar to this old Macromedia color picker?

[image]

It is pretty similar to web safe color, but the order is some different.

Comment: In some areas, trying to get an application, any application, to adhere to *your* specific desires in terms of the UI is a fruitless venture. One typically learns to adapt to the application's UI. (And perhaps file a feature request for the application.) While Adobe bought Macromedia, they've done a good job of removing any little idiosyncrasies that made it a more unique company in terms of the UIs for the applications. And since Macromedia also had *no comparable* app to Photoshop, I don't think this is possible in Photoshop. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Just a bit tricky.

So you know each of your swatch colours. If you iterate over all 240 colours and write them down as hex colours you're half way there. Or get a script to do that bit for you - like I did.

```
#000000
#000000
#000000
#003300
#006600
#009900
#00cc00
#00ff00
#330000
#333300
#336600
#339900
#33cc00
#33ff00
#660000
#663300
#666600
#669900
#66cc00
#66ff00
#333333
#000000
#000033
#003333
#006633
#009933
#00cc33
#00ff33
#330033
#333333
#336633
#339933
#33cc33
#33ff33
#660033
#663333
#666633
#669933
#66cc33
#66ff33
#666666
#000000
#000066
#003366
#006666
#009966
#00cc66
#00ff66
#330066
#333366
#336666
#339966
#33cc66
#33ff66
#660066
#663366
#666666
#669966
#66cc66
#66ff66
#999999
#000000
#000099
#003399
#006699
#009999
#00cc99
#00ff99
#330099
#333399
#336699
#339999
#33cc99
#33ff99
#660099
#663399
#666699
#669999
#66cc99
#66ff99
#cccccc
#000000
#0000cc
#0033cc
#0066cc
#0099cc
#00cccc
#00ffcc
#3300cc
#3333cc
#3366cc
#3399cc
#33cccc
#33ffcc
#6600cc
#6633cc
#6666cc
#6699cc
#66cccc
#66ffcc
#ffffff
#000000
#0000ff
#0033ff
#0066ff
#0099ff
#00ccff
#00ffff
#3300ff
#3333ff
#3366ff
#3399ff
#33ccff
#33ffff
#6600ff
#6633ff
#6666ff
#6699ff
#66ccff
#66ffff
#ff0000
#000000
#990000
#993300
#996600
#999900
#99cc00
#99ff00
#cc0000
#cc3300
#cc6600
#cc9900
#cccc00
#ccff00
#ff0000
#ff3300
#ff6600
#ff9900
#ffcc00
#ffff00
#00ff00
#000000
#990033
#993333
#996633
#999933
#99cc33
#99ff33
#cc0033
#cc3333
#cc6633
#cc9933
#cccc33
#ccff33
#ff0033
#ff3333
#ff6633
#ff9933
#ffcc33
#ffff33
#0000ff
#000000
#990066
#993366
#996666
#999966
#99cc66
#99ff66
#cc0066
#cc3366
#cc6666
#cc9966
#cccc66
#ccff66
#ff0066
#ff3366
#ff6666
#ff9966
#ffcc66
#ffff66
#ffff00
#000000
#990099
#993399
#996699
#999999
#99cc99
#99ff99
#cc0099
#cc3399
#cc6699
#cc9999
#cccc99
#ccff99
#ff0099
#ff3399
#ff6699
#ff9999
#ffcc99
#ffff99
#00ffff
#000000
#9900cc
#9933cc
#9966cc
#9999cc
#99cccc
#99ffcc
#cc00cc
#cc33cc
#cc66cc
#cc99cc
#cccccc
#ccffcc
#ff00cc
#ff33cc
#ff66cc
#ff99cc
#ffcccc
#ffffcc
#ff00ff
#000000
#9900ff
#9933ff
#9966ff
#9999ff
#99ccff
#99ffff
#cc00ff
#cc33ff
#cc66ff
#cc99ff
#ccccff
#ccffff
#ff00ff
#ff33ff
#ff66ff
#ff99ff
#ffccff
#ffffff
}
```

Secondly, have a look at [this post here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155558/how-can-i-easily-convert-a-plaintext-list-of-hex-values-to-an-adobe-aco-ase-colo) which explains that Photoshop can read a list of hex colours as a swatch, from a CSS file. It's just a list of hex colours with just a right bracket on the end!

Now for the tedious bit. Load that swatch as a .css file into Photoshop - only Photoshop will try to be clever and get rid of some duplicate colours. it's only a matter of replacing them (mainly black) and then placing them in the right order. This can be done with relative ease with the Preset Manager.

Boom! And you're done!

[image: Swatches]

I've added the swatch to [github](https://github.com/GhoulFool/colourcube)

I have corrected the error on the yellow row (3rd from bottom)